# Relative URL to server path conversion - Grails

Tags: grails, parameters, tags, gsp

In a custom tag, I am receiving as a parameter the url of a file, which I need to open.

I have this

```
/content/data.html
```

which is the output from

```
${createLinkTo(dir:'content',file:'data.html')}:
```

and I need the 'server path':

```
C:\mygrailsapp\web-app\content\data.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Spring application context to find resources. This works if it's under web-app folder:

```
class FooController {

   def grailsApplication

   def myAction = {
      String path = params.path // '/content/data.html'
      def resource = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource(path)
      String text = resource.inputStream.text
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach better than mine, so I deleted my answer.